# Unity MVC Controller constructor not being hit

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unity-container

I downloaded Unity.MVC 5.9.2 and I'm having issues with my controller being hit with the new dependency I need.  From what I've read, all I should have to do is register the type in the RegisterTypes method and Unity should take care of the rest

The error I receive:

Failed to select a constructor for System.String
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to select a constructor for System.String

I've followed all relevant tutorials and I'm still not knowing what I am missing here

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
/// </summary>
public static class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container =
      new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
      {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
          RegisterTypes(container);
          return container;
      });

    /// <summary>
    /// Configured Unity Container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or
    /// API controllers (unless you want to change the defaults), as Unity
    /// allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously
    /// registered.
    /// </remarks>
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below.
        // Make sure to add a Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your type's mappings here.
        container.RegisterType<ILoader, Loader>();
    }
}

public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private ILoader _loader;
    public SomeController (ILoader loader)
    {
        _loader = loader;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetBatches()
    {
        try
        {
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, "Unable to get batches for recurring mail.");
        }
    }
}

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(UnityConfig.Container);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

public static class UnityMvcActivator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Integrates Unity when the application starts.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(UnityConfig.Container));

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container));

        // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
        // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Shutdown()
    {
        UnityConfig.Container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no mention of Application_Start. Can you include your global.asax? Are you calling your contianer or static RegisterTypes from AppStart?

Comment: I added UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(UnityConfig.Container); to Application_Start and it still doesn't work.  I'm also not convinced I need this call do to the container being lazy loaded and calling RegisterTypes on the first call of it anyways